# Drawing multiple separate diagrams in one box in Excel 2010 (Subplots)

Tags: excel, excel-2010, diagram, subplot

I wish to have 4 different diagrams in one box (not with shared axis but 4 different diagram) like the ability of drawing subplots in MATLAB so that I could have 4 diagrams in one box.

This is an example of what I mean.

[image]

Comment: What does your raw data look like? Can you paste it in?

Comment: Dear MicroR, 
  The picture was an example but in my excel files I have maximum 10 rows and 15 columns. I exactly do not know how to paste it here that would be shown as table not only numbers without order.